# Pass javascript parameters in in-line html function

Tags: javascript, html

I want to pass more than one parameters into a function inside an event defined into html tag like this:

```
this.element.innerHTML += "<input id='inputx" + i + "' type='text' value='" + this.model.getGeometry(i).vertices[j].x  
        + "' onChange='tableChangeController.tableRowChanged(" + i ,  j +")' />"
```

If I put only one parameter it works well but with two like now, it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not a clean way to do this, but here you go:

```
this.element.innerHTML += "<input id='inputx" + i + "' type='text' value='" + this.model.getGeometry(i).vertices[j].x + "' onChange='tableChangeController.tableRowChanged(" + i + ", " + j +")' />"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this out:

```
this.element.innerHTML += "<input id='inputx" + i + "' type='text' value='" + this.model.getGeometry(i).vertices[j].x + "' onChange='tableChangeController.tableRowChanged(" + i + "," +  j +")' />"
```